# Passing constructor parameters for MXML-based custom Flex components

Tags: apache-flex, custom-component

I've implemented a MXML custom components and I would like to pass parameters to the constructor:

```
 newUser = new userComp("name");
```

instead of using set methods.

Is this possible if the custom components has been built in MXML (with `initialize=myPseudoCostructor()` method ?)

Or I can only set the parameter with an additional line of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't [pass variables](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-16179) into an MXML component's constructor.  I don't even believe it's possible to [*define* a constructor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf688f1-7ff1.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a3a) in an MXML component, though I could be wrong.  You can, however, setup properties which have default values, and are changed post-construction.

You could also create an initialization function which is also invoked post-construction.

Comment: ok, so if I create a custom component with mxml I can only set the variables later invoking its methods.

Comment: You can define a constructor in/of an MXML component, and you can even have parameters in that constructor; but the restriction is that all parameters to the constructor must be optional.

Comment: I'm getting `Multiple constructor definitions found.  Constructor may not be defined in <Script /> code.`  It says [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=basic_as_2.html) (in a note) that this is explicitly disallowed.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently run into this problem - what you can do is create an initialisation function which returns the component:

Inside the component (called, for argument's sake, MyComponent):

```
public function init(...args):MyComponent {

    //Add constructor code here

    return this;    
}
```

...when creating a component, you can invoke like this:

```
var myComp:MyComponent = new MyComponent().init(args);
```

As it returns the object, you can treat it as a constructor. I've had to use this method a lot lately, seems the best method for getting round the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
IN COMPONENT (cosa)

<fx:Declarations>
 <fx:String id="name">Jon Doe</String>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
 trace("hola "+name)
</fx:Script>
<s:Label text="Hola {name}"/>

IMPLEMENT
<cosa name="Juan Perez"/>
```